# How to read a stack trace in ASP.NET NullReferenceException message

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, nullreferenceexception

i have a code that is giving me a "NullReferenceException" in the production environment but in the development environment works fine.
So, i want to know how to understand this class of exceptions and read correctly the message that is being throw to my client.
Where is the critical information in the message?
If you see the image, the arrow number 1 i think is the main method where the error is being throw but then i see "+0", what's that mean? and what are the next arrow lines means?
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your tip, i have changed the title.

Comment: I don't know enough to answer; but I believe the +0 is how many bytes after that call to the next item.

Comment: They are offsets into the method.

Comment: And what those offsets mean? Can they help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this is where you'd see a line number, but when the pdb symbols are not deployed with your binaries, I believe it reverts to these numbers instead. I'm not positive if they are bytes, instructions, or some other unit to show where in the call tree the current execution is at. Include your PDB symbols with your publish and you should get better debugging information to track down your problem.